# Angular Material Table (<mat-table>) with datasource with multiple inner ARRAY attributes

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am currently successfully displaying a Material `<mat-table>` with a 'simple' async DataSource interface. I've provided pseudocode using an async 'DataSource' extended object which works below (invoke an http call eventually, if it interests you). However, I'm having difficulty doing this with an interface that has at least 2 (TWO) inner **ARRAYS** (see IHuhInterface further below) each with its own `<mat-table>`. How does one manage a data source and display mat-table pointing to an interface with at least TWO inner arrays?

...simple.interface.ts:

```typescript
interface ISimple {
    name: string;
    address: string;
}
```

and simple.component.ts is:
...

datasource = new SimpleDataSource(this.simpleService);

where...

```typescript
export class SimpleDataSource extends DataSource<any> {
    constructor(private simpleService: SimpleService) {
        super();
    }
    connect(): Observable<SimpleArray[]> {

        return this.simpleService.simpleList()
            .map( (simpleItems) => {
                return simpleItems;  // simple items returns by service
            },
            (error) => {
                alert('returned error placeholder');
                return error;
            })
            .catch( (exception) => {
                alert('serious exception placeholder');
                return of(exception);
            });
    }
    disconnect() {}
}
```

and the partial ISimpleInterface  template is:

```xml
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="ds">

    <!-- Name Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let simpleItemElement"> {{simpleItemElement.name}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- address Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="address">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Address </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let simpleItemElement"> {{simpleItemElement.address}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
....
```

**Above works.**
How do I do the above with an interface with TWO inner arrays each with it's own `<mat-table>`? Like this:

huh.interface.ts: ....

```typescript
interface IHuhInterface {
    table1Array:SomeArray1[];  // show in <mat-table> 1
    table2Array:SomeArray2[]   // show in <mat-table> 2
}
```

How can I use the two arrays in a template with two material tables which must be populated with those two arrays? Do I need TWO datasources...? or ..? Note the two arrays are from ONE http call so I don't want to make that call twice.

Many thanks!

PS: versions are:

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.1.3",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.0.3",
"@angular/common": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/core": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/forms": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/http": "^5.1.2",
"@angular/material": "^5.0.3",
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So finally found a clean solution with a few not so well documented nuances:

```typescript
dataSourceArray1 =  new MatTableDataSource(); <===**NUANCE**. should be clearly mandated.
dataSourceArray2 =  new MatTableDataSource(); <===**NUANCE**. should be clearly mandated.

ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getTwoArrays()
    .map( (twoArrays) => {
        this.dataSourceArray1.data = twoArrays.array1; <==NUANCE. 'data' update triggers change.
        this.dataSourceArray2.data = twoArrays.array2; <==NUANCE. 'data' update triggers change.
        return twoArrays;
    })
    .subscribe( (arrays) => {
        // do nothing.
    } );
}
```

Comment: RxJS update, we are supposed to be doing the pipe thing as of the date of my post.  

```getTwoArrays().pipe(
      map...)```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd have your service call made outside of the data source, and when it returns you provide the right data to each data source through some method like (`updateData(data)`) just by exposing the stream returned in the connect function and just pushing the new array manually.

Comment: thanks...can you share pseudo? I have not been able to trigger change detection to the table once async service returns data....